# Select elements under elements in Chrome Inspector

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can't seem to find the answer online, but I remember reading a Reddit thread where a user mentioned there is a way to allow you to inspect an element covered by another element in Chrome inspector by holding a key combination and clicking on it.

Anyone know the shortcut?